# Removing part of a String using value from another column

Tags: sql, t-sql, replace

I have a field that contains file paths to attachments, contained within the filename is the attachments "AttachmentID" which gets auto appended, but in some cases this ID is duplicated which is causing problems when my front-end tries to find the attachment. I want to remove the duplicate ID.

I'm thinking the best way to do this is using REPLACE but I don't know how I can tell SQL find the AttachmentID within the Path

Here's what I've written to find the records:

```
SELECT Path
FROM [Attachments].[dbo].[Attachments]
WHERE [Path] LIKE CONCAT ('%','-',[AttachmentID],'-','%')
```

I.e. `\\SERVERNAME\X\FILEPATH\ATTACHMENT\01928-01928-Filename.JPG`

I want it to read: `\\SERVERNAME\X\FILEPATH\ATTACHMENT\01928-Filename.JPG`

That number I'm removing is also stored independently in another column called AttachmentID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have answered my own question, sorry!

```
UPDATE [Attachments].[dbo].[Attachments]
SET Path = REPLACE(Path, CONCAT('-',[AttachmentID]), '')
WHERE [Path] LIKE CONCAT ('%','-',[AttachmentID],'-','%')
```

Since the additional ID is always prefixed by a hyphen, this seems to have worked.

Comment: Thank you! I've tried but it says I can't accept my own answer for another 2 days, sorry!